# Sort List in reverse in order

Tags: java, list, sorting, guava

I have List list1 in direct order. `List<String> list = Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(asu2);`

How to change order. And I don't know how to rewrite methods from extends class, please write with examples or speak clearly.

Comment: can you elaborate your question with example?

Comment: What exactly to you mean by "change order"? Reverse the list or apply a completely new order to it based on a specific ruleset?

Comment: You want the list to be sorted in the descending order. Right?

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov - I answered your question to get a simple descending order.

Comment: @assylias that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How I would do it is:

```
personsList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

And happy coding :)

Comment: It should've been selected as an answer. this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 123):

Use this:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Comment: Does this sort in the descending order or just reverse the order in which the elements were inserted?

Comment: It just reverse the order elements.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It doesn't sort a collection in descending order - merely switches last element with first, second to last with second, etc

Comment: The question in misleading, if the intent was to just reverse the list, this will work.

Answer (score 60):

There is a method [`reverseOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) in the `Collections` class which returns a `Comparator`.

You can use it like `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: I would consider your answer, since it would not be necessary to arrange for only after reverting. Your approach is capable of performing two operations in a single frame. I don't know about the others, but thank you.

Comment: Or just `list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());`

Answer (score 18):

you can reverse any type by just putting "-" or negative sign infront of your return.

```
Collections.sort(listed, new Comparator<Object>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        return -o1.getLeft().compareTo(o2.getLeft());

    }
});
```

Comment: And lets hope that `compareTo` will never return minimal integer because `-Integer.MIN_VALUE` is still `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Safest way would be swapping o1 with o2 like `return o2.getLeft().compareTo(o1.getLeft())`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to sort the list in reverse natural order, guava's Ordering has [a reverse method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#reverse%28%29):

```
List<String> list = Ordering.natural().reverse().sortedCopy(asu2);
```

Answer (score 3):

To reverse the order of items in List you can use [`Collections.reverse(List<?> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.reverse(List)` reverses the given list in place. You can also use Guava's [`Lists.reverse(List)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) to create a *view* backed by the given list that is in reverse order without copying it or modifying the original list.

And if you just want to create a list that is sorted in the reverse of the natural order, see @assylias's answer about `Ordering.natural().reverse()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this neater approach:

```
Collections.reverseOrder(
  Comparator.comparing(
    MyEntity::getAFieldToSortBy)));
```

Answer (score 0):

list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());