# Is there a simple way to sort a ArrayList<> with ASCII descend in java?

Tags: java

I hope to sort `myVideoFile` with ASCII descending, so I can get the result `newVideoFile.get(0)` is "d", `newVideoFile.get(1)` is "c", `newVideoFile.get(2)` is "b" and `newVideoFile.get(3)` is "a".

Is there a simple way to do that in java?

```
 List<String> myVideoFile=new ArrayList<>();

 myVideoFile.add("a");
 myVideoFile.add("b");
 myVideoFile.add("c");
 myVideoFile.add("d");
```

Comment: Use `Collections.sort` and pass `Collections.reverseOrder()` as your comparator.

Comment: Use Collections.reverse(myVideoFile);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort List in reverse order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073590/sort-list-in-reverse-order)

Comment: @1615903, no, that's for reversing a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Sorts the list in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is `Collections.sort()`. you have to enter your list(myVideoFile) and how to sort it(in your case: Collections.reverseOrder()).

So if I got your example right your code should lool like that:

```
 List<String> myVideoFile=new ArrayList<>();

 myVideoFile.add("a");
 myVideoFile.add("b");
 myVideoFile.add("c");
 myVideoFile.add("d");

 Collections.sort(myVideoFile, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

You can also easily test it by printing out your string in and forech-statment:

```
    for(String s : myVideoFile)
    {
        //Java way to print
        System.out.println(s);
        //Android way to print
        Log.i("TEST", s);
    }
```