# How to sort a Java ArrayList in Descending Order?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have to sort out 15 numbers that are given by a user in descending order. I can write how to sort them in ascending order but I don't know how to turn them. To use for-loop or something else?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort List in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073590/sort-list-in-reverse-in-order)

Comment: See [a link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-decreasing-order/5894862

Answer (score 6):

If you use Java 8 or above you can use this:

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

---

If you want to keep the initial ordering of the list, you can:

1. create a copy:

   ```
   List<YourType> copy = new ArrayList<>(yourList);
   ```

   And then sort the `copy`.
2. use streams:

   ```
   List<YourType> sorted = yourList.stream()
                                   .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use that example

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9);
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(list);
```

Show: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `arraylist` first then reverse it, like this:

```
Collections.sort(arraylist);
Collections.reverse(arraylist);
System.out.println(arraylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `Comparator.reverseOrder()` for that.